# install maven plugin in Eclipse Europaa 3.2.0

Tags: eclipse, maven, eclipse-europa

I am working on web objects project that uses a very old framework and our project is compatible in Eclipse Europa series only and now I want to run our project using maven instead of ANT builder tool. I run the project using maven via command prompt successfully but could not success in eclipse. So my question is: Can I install a maven plugin in Eclipse Europa 3.2.0?

One thing I mentioned again and again that my project is compatible for only Eclipse Europa and I have not found any maven plugin for Europa. If anyone knows any plugin then help us!

Comment: I doubt that you will find something which fits.

Comment: That means i have no options to do this!